# Python Converting Characters from Unicode to HTML

Tags: python, python-2.7

Hey guys I am trying to convert this in python 2.7.3:

```
the+c\xf8\xf8n
```

to the html string:

```
the+c%C3%B8%C3%B8n
```

It was original the `c\xf8\xf8n` but I did use a replace to use a + instead of the space.

I'm not entirely sure what convention the latter is I would use string replace but the convention changes by the different characters..

Thoughts?  Thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

You are *URL* encoding, not HTML. Use `urllib.quote`:

```
from urllib import quote
```

but make sure you encode to `UTF-8` first:

```
quote(inputstring.encode('utf8'))
```

This will quote the `+` explicitly; if you meant that to be a space character, you need to mark that as safe:

```
quote(inputstring.encode('utf8'), '+')
```

The latter form gives:

```
>>> quote(inputstring.encode('utf8'), '+')
'the+c%C3%B8%C3%B8n'
```

Comment: Doh! I totally spaced on the URL encoding I will try this out and post,  Thanks